# Bridging between network namespaces using tun or tap devices

Tags: networking, network-namespaces

I am trying to create two tap interfaces which are connected via a userspace program which should be able to see (and later modify) all packets going over the "wire". While this works when I use different hosts (and forward the packets via a TCP connection), I have trouble with this setup when both TAP interfaces are on the same host. I was suggested using seperate namespaces to make this work.

So my idea is the following:

- Set up tun1 in the root namespace
- Set up tun2 in the root namespace
- Connect the two using a userspace program (I use socat in the POC below)
- Move tun1 to a new namespace ns1
- Move tun2 to a new namespace ns2
- Ping between the interfaces from ns1 or ns2

However, when I do so, socat (or any other userspace "connector") gets an IO error when writing to the tap fd. How could I make this work?

My POC code looks like this:

```
openvpn --mktun --dev tun1 --user timos
openvpn --mktun --dev tun2 --user timos

ip link set dev tun1 up
ip link set dev tun2 up

ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev tun1
ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev tun2

socat TUN:192.168.1.1/24,tun-name=tun1 TUN:192.168.0.2/24,tun-name=tun2 &

ip netns add ns1
ip netns add ns2

ip netns exec ns1 ip link set dev lo up
ip netns exec ns2 ip link set dev lo up

ip link set tun1 netns ns1
ip link set tun2 netns ns2

ip netns exec ns1 ip link set dev tun1 up
ip netns exec ns2 ip link set dev tun2 up

ip netns exec ns1 ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev tun1
ip netns exec ns2 ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev tun2

ip netns del ns1
ip netns del ns2
```

A similar questions answer [Is it possible to send packets between network namespaces using only TUN/TAP interfaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481968/is-it-possible-to-send-packets-between-network-namespaces-using-only-tun-tap-int) seems to indicate that this should work, but I could not reproduce it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you state that you get an error, please always be sure to copy-and-paste both the command that led to the error as well as the error message itself into your question; these are usually required to correctly analyze the problem.

Comment: Is the zero in the second IP address of the socat command a typo?  Also, like AdminBee mentions, it would be useful to see the exact error message.